# Bootstrap 4 Tabs doesn't appear by URL

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-4

I have this HTML structure:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card p-2">
                <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="general-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#general" role="tab" aria-controls="general" aria-selected="true">Info generali</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="permalink-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#permalink" role="tab" aria-controls="permalink" aria-selected="false">Permalink</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="card p-3">
            <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">

                <!-- Infos tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="general" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                </div>

                <!-- Permalink tab -->
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="permalink" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="permalink-tab">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

The id="general" tab is the first to appear when you load the page, but I have the necessity to load sometimes directly the second tab id="permalink" but if I try to call it by the URL with something like this:

www.somesite.com/edit/4#permalink

Doesn't work: when the page loads, it doesn't call the #permalink tab but the #general tab.

Comment: Your above code applies `active` to the first tab.  For your second tab to show on page load `active` would have to programmatically be set to it, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tabs are activated by JS so linking to them via a fragment identifier won't do anything as the js has hidden them. 
You have to get the fragment from the url in the address bar with js and manually activate the tab.

Example:

`url = somethin#profile`

If there is a `#` in the link the show the tab

You can set this to a function and load it as soon as the dom is loaded or you can listen to an event.

cheers

```js
//var url = document.location.toString();
console.log('example link');
var url = 'something#profile';
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">HOME</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">PROFILE</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">MESSAGE</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">SETTINGS</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="tc"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or `$('.nav-pills a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');` for nav-pills

Comment: you can use window.location.hash to get the fragment